# how to run J2me emulator

Tags: java-me

When I run the program in j2me the emulator is not run and show that code what is mean? here the code.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\admintrator\My Documents\JavaMESDKProjects\MobileApplication4\nbproject\build-impl.xml:629: Execution failed with error code 1.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 minutes 1 second)
```

Comment: Please mention what platform u used.Sun wirless toolkit,netbeaans,eclipse,etc.Which u used?.Then only we give the correct information

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you do not have J2ME SDK installed on your computer.

[Download it](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/overview/index.html) and install on your computer.

After that specify the location of installed J2ME SDK in your Netbeans project "Platform" settings.

Also make sure that Java/bin folder, where javac.exe located is specified in the system PATH environment variable.

Comment: but i'm using J2ME SDK not Netbeans & i download the J2ME SDK from the oracle website and install it 4 times but unfortunately they give error here the error:                                   Starting emulator in execution mode
*** Error ***
Failed to connect to device 0!
Reason:
Emulator 0 failed to register in time!
bdj-run:
cdc-run:
profiler.check:
open-profiler:
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 6 seconds)

Comment: I have no idea what's going on in your case. Try to install [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I also experiencing this problem using sun wirless toolkit but my solution to this problem is somewhat irrational. When I'm going to run the application I disabling all my network adapter, LAN, WLAN even Bluetooth if you have but still I don't think that it will solve everything. You can try to do this if you wish but not suggesting the best way to do.